# React,Redux: Show all posts

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, fetch-api, redux-thunk

I'm a begineer to React, redux and web development. I'm making a CRUD application using `JSON placeholder` as dummy backend , `react` and `redux` for showing posts.

I want to render out all the posts form `JSON placeholder` and simply display it

**Post.js**

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react"
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux"
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom"
import { getPostAll } from "../redux/features/PostSlice"

  return (
    <>
      <div className="row mt-4 d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
        <h2 className="row mt-4 d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
          Dashboard
        </h2>
      <div>
        <h2 className="row mt-4 d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
          All Posts
        </h2>
        {/* {console.log(getPostAll)} */}
        {console.log(dispatch(getPostAll()))}
        {dispatch(getPostAll).forEach((element) => {
          console.log(element)
        })}
      </div>
    </>
  )
}

export default Posts
```

**PostSlice.js**

```js
import { createAsyncThunk, createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit"

export const getPost = createAsyncThunk("post/getPost", async ({ id }) => {
  return fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/${id}`).then((res) =>
    res.json()
  )
})

export const getPostAll = createAsyncThunk("posts/getPosts", async () => {
  return fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts`)
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((json) => console.log(json, typeof json, json[0].id))
})

// export const getPostAll = fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts")
//   .then((response) => response.json())
//   .then((json) => console.log(json))

export const deletePost = createAsyncThunk(
  "post/deletePost",
  async ({ id }) => {
    return fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/${id}`, {
      method: "DELETE",
    }).then((res) => res.json())
  }
)
export const createPost = createAsyncThunk(
  "post/createPost",
  async ({ values }) => {
    return fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts`, {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        Accept: "application/json",
        "Content-type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        title: values.title,
        body: values.body,
      }),
    }).then((res) => res.json())
  }
)
export const updatePost = createAsyncThunk(
  "post/updatePost",
  async ({ id, title, body }) => {
    return fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/${id}`, {
      method: "PUT",
      headers: {
        Accept: "application/json",
        "Content-type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        title,
        body,
      }),
    }).then((res) => res.json())
  }
)

const PostSlice = createSlice({
  name: "post",
  initialState: {
    post: [],
    loading: false,
    error: null,
    body: "",
    edit: false,
  },
  reducers: {
    setEdit: (state, action) => {
      state.edit = action.payload.edit
      state.body = action.payload.body
    },
  },
  extraReducers: {
    [getPost.pending]: (state, action) => {
      state.loading = true
    },
    [getPost.fulfilled]: (state, action) => {
      state.loading = false
      state.post = [action.payload]
    },
    [getPost.rejected]: (state, action) => {
      state.loading = false
      state.error = action.payload
    },
    [deletePost.pending]: (state, action) => {
      state.loading = true
    },
    [deletePost.fulfilled]: (state, action) => {
      state.loading = false
      state.post = [action.payload]
    },
    [deletePost.rejected]: (state, action) => {
      state.loading = false
      state.error = action.payload
    },
    [createPost.pending]: (state, action) => {
      state.loading = true
    },
    [createPost.fulfilled]: (state, action) => {
      state.loading = false
      state.post = [action.payload]
    },
    [createPost.rejected]: (state, action) => {
      state.loading = false
      state.error = action.payload
    },
    [updatePost.pending]: (state, action) => {
      state.loading = true
    },
    [updatePost.fulfilled]: (state, action) => {
      state.loading = false
      state.post = [action.payload]
    },
    [updatePost.rejected]: (state, action) => {
      state.loading = false
      state.error = action.payload
    },
  },
})
export const { setEdit } = PostSlice.actions
export default PostSlice.reducer
```

I want to display all the posts from the dummy database

I have tried looping using map functinality and forEach but not desired results.

Answer (score 1):

You want to keep the task of *requesting the posts* separate from the task of *accessing the posts*.

To request the posts, you want to `dispatch` your `getPostAll` action.  You only need to do this once, so put it inside a `useEffect`.

```
const dispatch = useDispatch();

useEffect(() => {
   dispatch(getPostAll());
}, []);
```

You don't need to return anything here.  Remember, we are separating those tasks.

It looks like you're not actually responding to the `getPostAll` thunk in your reducer?  That's a problem which you need to fix for this approach to work.

Use one or more `useSelector` hooks to access the current value of the redux state.  These values will update automatically as your reducer responds to the changes which were initiated by the `getPostAll`.  On your first render you will have no data, then you'll have no data but `loading: true`.  Finally you will have either posts or an error.  Your component needs to render the correct content for all of these cases.

```
const Posts = () => {

  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
     dispatch(getPostAll());
  }, []);

  const { post, loading, error } = useSelector(state => state.posts);

  // I find it easier to extract this part and `return` instead of using a bunch of `&&`
  const renderContent = () => {
    if (loading) {
      return <div>Loading...</div>;
    }
    if (error) {
      return <div>Error</div>;
    }
    if (post) {
      return (
        <div>
          {post.map(item => 
            <Post key={item.id} data={item}/>
          )}
        </div>
      );
    }
    return null;
  }

  return (
    <>
      <div className="row mt-4 d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
        <h2 className="row mt-4 d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
          Dashboard
        </h2>
      <div>
        <h2 className="row mt-4 d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
          All Posts
        </h2>
        {renderContent()}
      </div>
    </>
  )
}
```